# Dont see Master-detail relationship type field on Entitlement object

Tags: master-detail, entitlements

Why cannot I see Master-Detail Relationship as an option when I try to create a new field in Entitlement object? (See image)

[image: What I see]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entitlements is a standard object and therefore can't be on the detail side of a relationship.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm

Comment: That was my first thought too but one answer here made it seem like it was possible, although I'm guessing maybe he was incorrect?  https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gsTbAAI

Answer (score 0):

Entitlements already has a master-detail relationship with Account.

[image]

Comment: This does not answer the question as you can have IIRC up to 3 MD relationships on an object.